# Relationship between company-user and employee-users

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am trying to building a sales-system with the MEAN-stack but got stuck right in the beginning because I cannot find what I'm looking for on Google. I've been searching for days with no answers. Now to the problem.

Many companies should be able to create an account on the website. When x company is logged in they should be able to create an account for every employee on the company. These employee accounts should be able to create sales, show statistics on their monthly-sales etc. Somehow I have to have a relationship between x company with their employee accounts to display all the data from all employees on the company account.

I know there are tons of people who have done something similar. I cannot find what I am searching for because I do not know what to google. If someone knows what phrase I should search for, please reply.

Thanks for taking your time, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest an open-source solution to creating a SaaS project. It has this functionality built-in. You can simply set up a tenant (Company x) in your own admin panel, and the company can add their own users/roles/permissions to applications inside of their own dashboards. You can add applications to your project and enable them to certain tenants (companies) that you wish (in a modular fashion). Companies' data would also be split in their own separate databases, and you can simply update each application by itself (so essentially you update code once, but data is still separated between users).

I have just started using this platform about two weeks ago on my own SaaS startup, and I am very excited in what it can offer. It's called Innomatic and you can check it out at their website: innomatic.io .

It does seem as if they haven't been giving the project much attention lately, but it does work nevertheless, and you can just maintain your own Applications within the platform.

If you have any questions I would be happy to help you , since I have spent the last two weeks getting the ropes of this platform.